# Global Stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

What's the best way of implementing a global stylesheet that affects all directories of a website? I know it's possible to link to a stylesheet in the above directory via href="../style.css", however there must be a better way of doing this as this will get messy when you've got a number of levels to a website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use a relative url based on the document root of your site `/style/style.css`

Comment: HTML *must* know where to interpret the stylesheet from. You can only do this kind of stuff with languages like PHP, where the absolute path is stored and can be re-used. Most websites today even use absolute urls like `http://www.mywebsite.com/styles/main.css`. In PHP you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/styles/main.css'` to have a complaint path everywhere.

Comment: @Allendar No they do not. They use a relative path based on the document root.

Comment: @PeeHaa doesn't the OP mean to use the Stylesheet anywhere? The `..` will only go up a level. Also on the other hand it looks like the OP wants to know if there is a way to automatically include a global style in each page he/she has on his/her site. But maybe I'm wrong. Just trying to assist :)

Comment: @Allendar I'm not talking about traversing directories using `..` I'm talking about a relative path `/whatever` which is always based on the document root no matter from where it is called.